# unknown version of the X Window System installed. Not installing X Window System drivers

Tags: unity, drivers, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu in a virtualbox, when I try to install guest additions I get the error:

```
Warning: unknown version of the X Window System installed.  Not
installing X Window System drivers.  ...done. Installing graphics
libraries and desktop services components ...fail! (See the log file
/var/log/vboxadd-install-x11.log for more information.)
eddie@ubuntu:/media/eddie/VBOXADDITIONS_4.3.18_96516$ Xorg -version
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and virtualbox 4.3.18.

My X.Org X server version is: 1.15.1.

When I do:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

I get the following:

```
libGL error: failed to authenticate magic 3 libGL error: failed to
load driver: vboxvideo OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc. OpenGL
renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits) OpenGL
version string:  2.1 Mesa 10.1.3

Not software rendered:    no Not blacklisted:          yes GLX
fbconfig:             yes GLX texture from pixmap:  yes GL npot or
rect textures: yes GL vertex program:        yes GL fragment program: 
yes GL vertex buffer object:  yes GL framebuffer object:    yes GL
version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the Virtualbox Guest Addition ISO file, try using the following commands in the terminal on the guest Ubuntu Virtual Machine :

1. Update apt-get. `apt-get update`
2. Install dependencies `apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
3. Install guest additions `apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11`

Use `sudo` before the commands if required.

Comment: On third step I get an error saying `The following packages have unmet dependencies. virtualbox-guest-x11: Depends: xorg-video-abi-15 Depends xserver-xorg-core (>=2:1.14.99.902)`

Comment: This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In above answer,  instead of step 3, run the following commands in the terminal on the guest Ubuntu Virtual Machine.

```
apt-get install xorg-video-abi-15  xserver-xorg-core unity-control-center libcheese-gtk23  libcheese7 libclutter-1.0-0  libclutter-gtk-1.0-0  libcogl15  libclutter-gst-2.0-0  gstreamer1.0-clutter
```

4. Install guest additions `apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11`

Use `sudo` before the commands if required.